# MySQL Database Error when using Convert or Cast (String to Interger)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

Running into the following error in MySQL. I have tried using convert as well with no luck. The customer would like to be able to filter data where a customer ID will be something like: BOB102, REB293, REC203. I will need to pretty much be searching for customer numbers > 200, and so on.

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INTEGER)) > 0 )' at line 6**

```
SELECT `orders_jobs`.* 
FROM (`orders_jobs`) 
INNER JOIN `orders_users` ON `orders_jobs`.`customer` = `orders_users`.`id` 
WHERE `orders_jobs`.`active` = 1 
AND `orders_users`.`active` = 1 
AND ( CAST(orders_users.cust_number AS INTEGER)) > 0 )
```

Now these may not always be 3 string characters long it might be 4 also, ie: BKER2938

**NOTE**: As Edga mentioned, I needed to use UNSIGNED instead of integer, but because of the characters it is converting all to 0 instead, is there possibly a different method?

**Data Examples (for the field cust_number):**
MTQ32499,BGM31620,RES42935,CAM31717,CRED31672
(note the last one is 4 chars. I believe it will only be 3 or 4 characters long)

I need to return only the customers who have cust_number > 40000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
CAST AS SIGNED
```

or

```
CAST AS UNSIGNED
```

More information [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html)

-- edit

As a workaround you can use [SUBSTRING](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en//string-functions.html#function_substring) if 5 last characters are always numeric

Comment: Thank you, this did remove the issue though I guess CAST is not what I need as it seems all are set as 0 now (Since it's not interpreting the number). Is there a way I can either remove the strings and cast it or a different function that might be helpful?

Comment: Seems to give me the same result (nothing is returned greater than 0) when using CONVERT(orders_users.cust_number, SIGNED) > 0

Comment: Could you please give us sample of data you want to convert, and your desired result ?

Comment: Just added to the question

Comment: I don't know how complicated those numbers are, but if there are always in the end you could use SUBSTRING to only check last 5 characters. Would that work?

Comment: Good idea, was trying to make it work from front to back but hadn't thought of the reverse. Let me see if I can make that work

Comment: I've been trying a few methods with this still with no luck. Would this be correct? SELECT `orders_jobs`.*, `orders_users`.`cust_number` FROM (`orders_jobs`) INNER JOIN `orders_users` ON `orders_jobs`.`customer` = `orders_users`.`id` WHERE `orders_jobs`.`active` = 1 AND `orders_users`.`active` = 1 AND CONVERT(SUBSTR(orders_users.cust_number, LENGTH(orders_users.cust_number) - 5), UNSIGNED) < 10000

Comment: Can you try to simplify it to `SUBSTRING(orders_users.cust_number), -5)`, hopefully it will give you the same results and will shorten your query